# ID is 0 in model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have been looking at this for hours trying to find an answer I can't seem to find it.

On my `HttpPost Create` action, my ID is 0 and I can't figure out why.

Here is my *GET* action for *Create*

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.activityID = new SelectList(db.test1, "ID", "text");
        ViewBag.CtyID = new SelectList(db.test2, "ID", "cty");
        ViewBag.AircraftID = new SelectList(db.test3, "ID", "RegNum");
        return View();
    }
```

The `Create` action is very basic:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID, /*..more properties*/")] DailySummary dailySummary)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.DailySummaries.Add(dailySummary);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "/*Controller*/");
        }

        ViewBag.activityID = new SelectList(db.test1, "ID", "text", dailySummary.activityID);
        ViewBag.CtyID = new SelectList(db.test2, "ID", "cty", dailySummary.CtyID);
        ViewBag.ACID = new SelectList(db.test3, "ID", "RegNum", dailySummary.ACID);
        return View(dailySummary);
    }
```

On my *Create* view I have:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.ID)
```

and it is still being passed as 0.

Any ideas on why this isn't being binded properly?

Comment: Show how you implement the GET action. Inspect your HTML.

Comment: You are creating and not updating, shouldn't the ID  always be 0 on a new entity ? What are you expecting the ID to be?

Comment: @CodeCaster I updated my question to show the *GET* action

Comment: @JamesDev When I create, I would expect the ID to become 1 once it saved.. or whatever number is next since it is set to auto increment

Comment: You don't pass a view-model at all in your `GET` action

Comment: Entity framework will handle the save and the auto increment if the Id is a primary key. On a new entity the Id will be 0. I suspect you will not get an error if you save this way.

Comment: Also what is with the ViewBag passing data ? This is what the ViewModel is for please use it.

Comment: @JamesDev The ViewBag's were auto created when I started this project

Comment: That doesn't mean you can't refactor it. It will save you a lot of pain in future when your project scales up by hey that's my opinion. You are really breaking the rules of MVC which is disappointing.

Comment: @JamesDev I am confused of what the rules are then, when i wasn't the one to implement these ViewBag's.. also I in my *GET* action I added `DailySummary daily = new DailySummary();` and it now works. Can you provide an example using a ViewModel instead of ViewBags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this without using viewbag would be to create models for each of the drop down lists, they might look something like...

```
public class ActivityVM
{
 public int ActivityID {get; set;}
 public string ActivityDesc {get; set;}

}

public class CityVM
{
 public int CityID {get; set;}
 public string CityDesc {get; set;}

}


public class RegVM
{
 public int RegID {get; set;}
 public string RegDesc {get; set;}

}
```

your create view model might look something like...

```
public class MyCreateVM
{

  public int ActivityID {get; set;}
  public int CityID {get; set;}
  public int RegID {get; set;}

  public List<ActivityVM> Activities{ get; set; }
  public List<CityVM>  Cities{ get; set; }
  public List<RegVM> Registrations{ get; set; }
  ... etc
}
```

and your create controller action might look like:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{

  MyCreateVM viewModel = new MyCreateVM();

  viewModel.ActivityList = myActivityService.GetAll();
  viewModel.City = myCityService.GetAll();
  viewModel.RegList  = myRegService.GetAll();

  return View(viewModel);
}
```

in your view you'd do:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.ActivityID, new SelectList(Model.Activities, "ActivityID, "ActivityDesc"))
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.CityID, new SelectList(Model.Cities, "CityID, "CityDesc"))
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.RegID, new SelectList(Model.Registrations, "RegID, "RegDesc"))
  </div>
</div>
```

then when that gets passed back to your controller you could do:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MyCreateVM viewModel)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    db.DailySummaries.Add(viewModel)
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  else
  {
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "There was a problem");

    //...some code here to repopulate drop downs

    return View(viewModel);
  }
}
```

Comment: even though this isn't the answer to the question, I really appreciate the time you took to do this.  Upvote plus accepted.

Comment: Ha! Thanks... I know it didn't solve the initial problem but you did ask for an example using view model instead of viewbag :)